# How do you read data into an InfoPath from a server?

Tags: sql-server, database, infopath

I have an InfoPath 2010 form where I want a user to select an 'employee name' and the rest of the fields populate with the specific employees data. I have been working with the rules to try to manage how this should be done and working with the data connections, but don't quite have it. At this time when I select the employees name from 'employee name' drop down, the phone field and extension field also contain the employees name. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Thank You

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the data connection for all the fields and need to apply filter based on the value selected for employee name on the other fields.

In your employee phone field text box(/dropdown box) right click and select Programming > Changed event

Now you have to define the function State_Changed(object sender, XmlEventArgs e)

Create an Xpath navigator to retreive the value selected in the employee name field. Use this as the filter value and write a query to retreive the phone information.

Note: the phone field should have the option show data on form load unchecked in its datasource.

Comment: @Shankar89: In InfoPath 2010, when I right click the phone field text box(/dropdown box), Programming is not an option.

Comment: @CompGeekes:Its nothing but the code behind for the infopath form.If you have the VSTA installed your machine, under Tools > Programming, select Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Application. You have to add a handler for the control field in your code behind.

Comment: @Shankar89: At the present moment, I am unable to work with Visual Studio. I have to create a VM in order to work with VS to do anything with SharePoint. InfoPath, to what I have been advised, can be easily worked with without using code. Is there a way I can do this without having to "go behind"? I am very new to this so if I dont have to use code at the moment, that would be extremely helpful. Thank You. And How do I get to the code behind? Sorry, for seemling like I have no clue to what I am doing, I don't, but I am trying to. :)

Comment: @CompGeekess:If yours is not a browser enabled form, check the master/details control option available in infopath form.This is pretty straight forward and does not involve any code.

Comment: @Shankar89- Sorry for the delay. We are working on the system so that I may be able to do some coding :), can't wait for it to be completed! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @CompGeekess: No Problem! Please let me know if you face any problem coding!